# Get count of array elements of multiple documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to know total count of tags in `mongodb`. For example in below documents there are total 5 tags.

My documents are like-

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59c2102e2526c34768e405f5"), 
    "Name" : "Ashish", 
    "tags" : [
        "java", 
        "python", 
        "c"
    ]
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("62c2102e2526c34768e405l8"), 
    "Name" : "Binay", 
    "tags" : [
        "Dotnet", 
        "perl"
    ]
}
```

Comment: It is a very basic question but i am completely new in MongoDB. 
Thanks

Comment: `db.collection.aggregate([{ "$group": { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": { "$size": "$tags" } } }}])`. Very basic questions already have answers. Look for them before posting please.